# Flutter error - The specific widget that could not find a Material ancestor was:

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, iconbutton

I am using the `Align` widget to place an Icon button at the bottom center of the screen.

However, I get the following error and I'm unable to resolve it:

*`The specific widget that could not find a Material ancestor was:
 IconButton`*

My code:

```
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      child: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition:
        CameraPosition(target: LatLng(1,1), zoom: 15),
        onMapCreated: (map) {
          mapReady;
        },),
    ),
    Align(
      alignment:Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.next_week), onPressed: (){}),
    )
  ],
```

If I replace the IconButton widget with for example a Text widget it works well.

Could you please explain why it doesn't work, why the IconButton needs a Material ancestor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because as per documentation of IconButton (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html)

> An icon button is a picture printed on a Material widget that reacts
> to touches by filling with color (ink).
>
> [..]
>
> Requires one of its ancestors to be a Material widget.

IconButton uses most likely ThemeData as well as other things which MaterialApp normally provides.

Is there a reason you dont use MaterialApp as ancestor?

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap you stack (or the parent in general) with Scaffold you will n get this error.

In this case, if you wrap your IconButton with Material Widget,i believe it will fix the problem:

```
  Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: Material(
        child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.next_week), onPressed: () {})),
  )
```